# Extjs 7.0 Calendar headers not aligned with columns

Tags: extjs, localization, calendar, header, extjs7

Using the Calendar component in Extjs 7.0 we noticed that the header cells didn't line up correctly with their columns if the language was set to Dutch:

[image: calendar]

When checking the source code I found the place where these values are added in the cell html;
In Ext.calendar.header.Base, in the setHeaderText function the following code exists:

```
var me = this,
            D = Ext.Date,
            value = me.getValue(),
            format = me.getFormat(),
            domFormat = me.domFormat,
            cells = me.cells,
            len = cells.length,
            useDates = me.useDates,
            cell, i;

        if (!value) {
            return;
        }

        value = D.clone(value);

        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            cell = cells[i];

            if (useDates) {
                cell.setAttribute('data-date', D.format(value, domFormat));
            }

            cell.setAttribute('data-day', value.getDay());
            cell.innerHTML = D.format(value, format);
            value = D.add(value, D.DAY, 1);
        }
```

The innerHtml is set by formatting the Date(D) object which results in the 3 characters of that day. If you change this to just setting a 4 char value like cell.innerHTML = 'Test' the headers line up just fine:

[image: Test]

But for some reason this doesn't work when using the D.format value. If somebody has any idea what causes this, I would love to hear.

I can't seem to test if this also goes wrong in another language cause for some reason my packages can't be loaded in anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can set(or fix) localization override localization constants.
Calendar use `Ext.Date.dayNames` and `Ext.Date.getShortDayName()`.

All constants list you can see in [localization package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSeDZ.png).

[Fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/35is&view/editor)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the example.

We have made our own Localization class since we needed to load the translations from our own server which should override the 'Locale' property. When i changed the dayNames and getShortDayName function in there I didn't notice a difference so maybe this override isn't doing what I think it should be doing.

But then I'm unsure where it gets it's translations from.

Comment: Ah, I found that in our app.json we set the "locale": "nl", and in Ext-local-nl.js it actually sets the dayNames. So if I change them in there I see them change in my calendar. But still the headers are aligned with the columns tho, that's a shame.

Comment: Aligned with column like on first your screenshot? it looks like you did something with styles

Comment: Yea aligned like in the first screenshot, we didn't add any styles to the Calendar component. We just used it straight out of the box. But I tried adding a width to the calendar-header-cell and for some reason this fixes it. Even if i resize the window or use different phone using the device toolbar it still looks good.